# How the Thread scheduler execute this code ?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class CustomThread extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        IntStream.range(0, 3).parallel().forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.println("Child Thread :- "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+x));
    }
}

public class CustomThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomThread customThread = new CustomThread();     
        customThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        customThread.setName("CustomThread");
        customThread.start();


        CustomThread customThread1 = new CustomThread();        
        customThread1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        customThread1.setName("CustomThread1");
        customThread1.start();

        IntStream.range(0, 3).parallel().forEachOrdered(x ->                       
                System.out.println("Parent Thread :- "+x));


    }
}
```

By default both threads are having same priority(5) that's why why we can't expect proper ordering result but if we set child thread priority - how the execution will be done by Thread- Scheduler.

Comment: You can't expect anything unless you explicitly provide synchronization to control the behaviour of those threads. The priority doesn't affect anything here.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the response,can you please explain a bit this point i.e "synchronization to control the behavior of those threads" then i can have a clear point cut mechanism of that.

Comment: It's multi-threading basics. Read up on those.

Comment: For a start refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0):

While the scheduler shall prefer threads with higher priority, it is not save to rely on any behaviour. Use synchronized blocks and other mechanisms to ensure thread safety, as defined in

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html